# custom ticks in js plotting library flot

Tags: jquery, html, flot

I can't get flot to register the custom ticks I'm sending it. My code works fine but the ticks are still appearing as whatever default ticks flot chooses.

HTML:

```
<div class="flot" id="flotcontainer"></div>';
```

JS:

```
var $hist_data = [[1.0, 0],[2.0, 2],[3.0, 1],[4.0, 1],[5.0, 0],[6.0, 1],[7.0, 2],[8.0, 1],[9.0, 1],[10.0, 1]];

var $hist_ticks = [[1.0, 1.0],[2.0, 2.0],[3.0, 3.0],[4.0, 4.0],[5.0, 5.0],[6.0, 6.0],[7.0, 7.0],[8.0, 8.0],[9.0, 9.0],[10.0, 10.0]];



<script type="text/javascript">

    $.plot($("#flotcontainer"), 

        [
          {
            data: $hist_data,

            bars: { show: true, barWidth: 1, fill:0.8},

            color: "#227dda",

            xaxis: {ticks: $hist_ticks}

          }
        ]

    );

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your `xaxis` properties mixed up. Confusingly, there is an `xaxis` property of the data itself, but this is just a number that you use to specify which axis that data series should be plotted against. To actually set the axis ticks, you need to use the options parameter passed to `.plot`:

```
$.plot($("#flotcontainer"), [{ 
        data: $hist_data,

        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: 1,
            fill: 0.8
        },

        color: "#227dda"

    }], {xaxis: { ticks: $hist_ticks} }

);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WGBx9/1/)